# Swapping 2 function pointers without a temporary variable

Tags: c, function-pointers

Swapping two void pointers is easy without using any extra memory:

```
void* p1;
void* p2;

//...

p1 = ((uintptr_t)p1) ^ ((uintptr_t)p2);
p2 = ((uintptr_t)p1) ^ ((uintptr_t)p2);
p1 = ((uintptr_t)p1) ^ ((uintptr_t)p2);
```

But to swap function pointers must I use another pointer? (as they are not guaranteed to fit into any integer type).

```
void (*p1)();
void (*p2)();

//...

void (*tmp)() = p1;
p1 = p2;
p2 = tmp;
```

Can anyone give me an example of a fully portable method that will swap function pointers without using a temporary variable?

Comment: Suggest changing `fully portable code` to `fully portable way/method`

Comment: This kind of thing is so unecessary, just use a third variable.

Comment: You want to avoid a temporary variable because...?  Your first example rejects three assignments for a solution that involves three assingments _plus_ three XOR calculations.  I grew up when memory was "precious" (I remember adding a 32**k**B memory module to a TRS80 clone) but it can't be _that_ scarce these days.

Comment: Are you asking because you have a practical need to eliminate the temporary variable, or is this just an intellectual puzzle?

Comment: I'm just interrested in learning something, it seems like there is a bit of a hole in the spec. to me.

Comment: @TripeHound: For most architectures, the assignments and the xor are a single instruction, while a branch might take multiple clocks. It is just badly written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works, because aliasing through (unsigned) char is allowed:

```
void (*p1)();
void (*p2)();

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(p1); ++i) {
    ((unsigned char *)&p1)[i] ^= ((unsigned char *)&p2)[i]
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(p2); ++i) {
    ((unsigned char *)&p2)[i] ^= ((unsigned char *)&p1)[i]
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(p1); ++i) {
    ((unsigned char *)&p1)[i] ^= ((unsigned char *)&p2)[i]
}
```

Comment: While aliasing on char is guaranteed to work, casting a function pointer to a pointer to arithmetic type is **undefined behavior** and not covered by the C standard. For readability reasons, you really don't want have code like this anyhow..

Comment: @Lundin I am not casting a function pointer to `unsigned char *`, I am casting a "function pointer pointer" which is a pointer to a regular object.

Comment: I still have a bad feeling about this.

Comment: I just have no time right now (and as I never would have the idea to write such code;-, I'm not very enthusiastic to play language-lawyer here). DId you actually check the [_effective type_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) rules?

Comment: @Olaf I did not re-check them for this answer but I have read them before, enough to be pretty confident about this answer.  Note the exception in the next paragraph, allowing access through an lvalue of "a character type."  Other parts of the standard are relevant to this answer too, such as the parts that talk about "representations."

Comment: @TavianBarnes: That's why I just have the feeling. I just cannot point at it, so for now, I just will accept it as-is +1.

Comment: @Olaf "I just cannot point at it" ... because you are a `void` pointer? :D

Comment: Feeling more like `volatile` today. But that feeling is not very `const`ant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather write it like this (**see below, however**):

```
uintptr_t up1 = (uintptr_t)p1;
uintptr_t up2 = (uintptr_t)p2;

p1 ^= p2;
p2 ^= p1;
p1 ^= p2;
```

On most architectures which have `sizeof(uintptr_t)` <= register size, this is three instruction == 3 clocks, likely as much as the other version (unless the casts cost extra). However, I would prefer the temp-variant for most architectures.

**Warning:** it is **not safe**: While [6.3.2.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1) states "`void *` can be converted safely between a pointer to *any object* type" and [7.20.1.4p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4p1) states "`unitptr_t` can hold a `void *`", [3.15](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15) restricts the term *object* to the data storage only. Functions reside in code storage. (Thanks to the comments)

So, do not apply this to function pointers!

Note, this is less obvious anyways than the temp-version and a compiler might very well use this code if it detects the temp-version's pattern.

Comment: This is incorrect per the letter of the C standard: neither `void *` nor `uintptr_t` is required to be conversion-safe with, nor even the same *size* as any function pointer type.  (However, both POSIX and Windows do guarantee conversion safety between `void *` and function pointers.)

Comment: (Note the phrasing in the text you quote: "A pointer to any **object** type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer." Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Ok, I just checked. `object` is really just `data` objects. So, I agree, a function is not an object.

Answer (score -3):

Use the xor swap algoritm:

```
*p1 = *p1 ^ *p2;
*p2 = *p1 ^ *p2;
*p1 = *p1 ^ *p2;
```

Comment: The `^` operator is not defined for function types though

Comment: @TavianBarnes: He is xor-ing the functions themselves even. (what yields `scanf ^ printf`? Half-duplex?